# how to open a new window from menu widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to develop a simple Gui that display different pages when the button in the menu is clicked and i have been able to make other buttons work but the menu is giving me errors.
just like other apps that from the menu person can navicate the app.
when i run the code and click on newtest in file menu, i get this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/py script/helium1/test.py", line 34, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'show_frame'
```

here is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt




LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

def messageFunction (client, userdata, message):
    topic = str(message.topic)
    message = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print(topic + " " + message)

HeliumClient = mqtt.Client("xokaxvwt") 
HeliumClient.username_pw_set(username = "xokaxvwt", password="MGlEiIwOHM9-")
HeliumClient.connect("m16.cloudmqtt.com", 15998) 
HeliumClient.subscribe("Switch_1")
HeliumClient.subscribe("Switch_2")
HeliumClient.on_message = messageFunction 
HeliumClient.loop_start()


class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, controller)
        self.controller = controller

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New Test",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit")



class Helium(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.menubar = MenuBar(self, parent)
        self.controller.config(menu=self.menubar)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()



class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


app = Helium()

#creating Date/time
def display_time():
    Date = datetime.datetime.now()
    Date_Label['text'] = Date 
    app.after(1000, display_time)


Date_Frame = LabelFrame(app, text= "Date/time")
Date_Frame.place(x=790, y=5, height=35, width=200)
Date_Label = Label(Date_Frame)
Date_Label.grid(column=0, row=0)

app.geometry('1000x450')
app.title("Helium")
app.resizable(False, False)
display_time()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `parent` argument to `MenuBar` but it's expecting a controller. You also need to pass the `parent` to the superclass, not `controller`. You need to create `MenuBar` like this:

```
class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
    ...

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.menubar = MenuBar(self)
        ...
```